# Specman coverage: How to cover only that some transition occurred?

Tags: specman, e

I need to make sure that at least 1 change occurred in a specific uint item X, i.e. X had 2 different values (it is unknown what specific values). Something like this:

```
cover some_event {
    item X : uint = some_uint using no_collect;
    transition X using when = (prev_X != X);
};
```

** The code causes compilation error

Is it possible to define such coverage in Specman?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

what you wrote is almost accurate, but instead of "when" - use "ignore"

```
cover some_event is {
    item X : uint = some_uint using no_collect;        
    transition X using ignore = (prev_X == X);
};
```